# Need to add a 3 second delay before scene switch on trigger collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

ok so once the player fulfills the criteria, the player enters the trigger collider of the npc and a dialogue and a scene change is triggered so that he may proceed to level 2. I need to give the player time to read the dialogue (4 seconds) so I need to add a delay before scene switch. How EXACTLY will I do that? (I'm just a beginner so be clear).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;
public class SceneChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int sceneNumber;
    public Text counter;
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("player") && counter.text == "X 3")
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneNumber);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add delay using Coroutine

Documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{

    if (collision.CompareTag("player") && counter.text == "X 3")
    {

        StartCoroutine(SceneLoadWithDelay(sceneNumber, 4));

    }
}

IEnumerator SceneLoadWithDelay(int sceneNum, int numSeconds)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(numSeconds);

    SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneNum);
}
```

Comment: Im not a 100% sure for `OnTriggerEnter2D` but it might be able to be a Coroutine out of the box, just make it return IEnumerator, no need to call StartCoroutine (I know it works for the 3D versions like `OnTriggerEnter`)

Answer (score 2):

You can use coroutine.

```
 IEnumerator LoadSceneWithDelay()
{
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(4);
   SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneNumber);
}
```

And call:

```
StartCoroutine(LoadSceneWithDelay);
```

https://forum.unity.com/threads/delay-before-loading-a-new-scene.512121/

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned you an use a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) but actually [`OnTriggerEnter2D`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider2D.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) itself can directly be a coroutine without needing `StartCorotine` like

```c#
private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    // for IEnumerators "yield break" equals a "return" for void
    if (!collision.CompareTag("player") || !string.Equals(counter.text, "X 3")) yield break;

    // yield allows to interupt the routine here, render this frame
    // and continue from hier in the next frame
    // WaitForSeconds is a special IEnumerator provided by Unity for doing 
    // exactly that: yield until the given time has passed - then it allows to continue
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(4f);    

    SceneManager.LoadScene (sceneNumber);
}
```

---

Alternatively in a simple case of a delay you could also use [`Invoke`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Invoke.html)

```c#
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (!collision.CompareTag("player") || !string.Equals(counter.text, "X 3")) return;

    Invoke("SwitchScene", 4f);  
}

private void SwitchScene()
{
    SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNumber);
}
```